# In Civil War, how could the prison hold this person?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*,

> The Avengers are split on whether to sign the Sokovia Accords.

On the side in favor are

> The Vision, Black Widow, Iron Man, War Machine, Spider-Man (kinda),

On the side against are

> The Scarlet Witch, Falcon, Hawkeye, Captain America, Ant-Man, and the Winter Soldier, and later the Black Panther

When Captain America and

> Bucky

seek to escape in order to stop Baron Zemo, the other three members of their group are taken into custody, and imprisoned

> by the United Nations on a submarine.

Now, most of these people are essentially powerless without their gadgets, and could be contained quite readily by a normal prison. By contrast,

> Wanda the Scarlet Witch is very powerful, able to summon up enough force to throw the Vision through several dozen floors and into the ground. Even Bucky Barnes, with his mechanical arm, was able to punch his way out of the similar prison that he was contained in earlier—and he doesn't have much on Wanda. 
> This doesn't even take into account her ability to control the minds of her captors.

**How was the prison able to contain someone with that power set?**

Comment: Every time Wanda uses her powers, she uses excessive amounts of hand-gestures. In the prison, she's completly restrained, and only able to move her head. Also, there's a collar on her neck, with some blinking LEDs, maybe it's an inhibitor of some sorts?

Comment: Plus, the first time Stark entered the room, she appeared to be shivering.  I thought she was drugged.

Comment: Related: [How can Wanda Maximoff (The Scarlet Witch) be realistically imprisioned in the MCU?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/53716/49)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For clarification, she did not throw Vision through several dozen floors; she controlled his density shifting (first, to allow the person he was holding to slip through his grasp...literally) to make him so heavy that he *fell* through those floors.

In addition to restricting her hand gestures with a straightjacket, she is also shown wearing a lit electronic collar.  While I don't believe it's explicitly stated in the film, the implication is that the collar would inhibit her abilities in some way.

Setting aside the collar's capabilities, she's never been shown to use her powers without making hand gestures to control or guide the effects.

Comment: I didn't catch that! I assumed she was just applying a very great pressure to him. Nice catch, if so.

Comment: It's a bit subtle, but they foreshadowed it a bit by reminding the audience that her powers were also granted by the stone in Vision's head.

Comment: It's also possible that the collar could knock her out should she escape.

Comment: Where is it been said or shown?

Comment: do you have any sources to back up your 1st paragraph?

Comment: @RedCaio It's directly confirmed in the director's commentary.